# Android Studio Lint Warning: Unstable @Incubating

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-dsl

After migrating from Groovy to Kotlin DSL the `settings.gradle` is now getting a lint warning about the usage of this code

```
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://jitpack.io")
        }
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Currently using AGP `8.1.3`

Even when creating a new project using the IDE's template that is in Kotlin DSL, the above configuration exist and also got warning.

Why this is not showing when using Groovy, it seems there is an issue with Kotlin DSL or the lint just cannot detect it when in Groovy?

Comment: it's a warning, not an error. and seems pretty self explanatory.. What is your question?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski but why it is only showing after converting it to Kotlin, in Groovy this is not a warning?

Comment: Now, this is a question. I'd suggest you update your post and include it at the bottom for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you convert the `dependencyManagement {}` block back to `Groovy` DSL and try to navigate to `repository` handler, for example, you end up in the same file with same `@Incubating` annotations:
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core-api/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/initialization/resolve/DependencyResolutionManagement.java#L44

But why does it show warnings for Kotlin but not for Groovy?
According to this answer in the Gradle GitHub repo:
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/20328#issuecomment-1083788360

The problem is not with Gradle. It's the way `Intellij`-based IDEs run their inspections on `.gradle` and `.kts` files. The `Unstable API usage` inspection not working for `.gradle` files for some reason.

Seems like to make it work `IntelliJ` guys should add it to the `Gradle` sections in their Inspection catalog. As for now, seems like it can handle only `@Deprecated` annotation

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought there still something needed for us to do for this part after migration but it looks like it is what it is as of the moment.